# Returning a Comparator from a Function in Java

Tags: java, functional-programming, comparator

Is it possible to return a `Comparator` from a `java.util.function.Function` in Java?

I tried this in the following (contrieved) example, but Eclipse tells me that there is a syntax error (*"Syntax error on token "amountOfPages", delete this token"*):

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class App 
{
    private record Book(Integer nrOfPages) {};
    
    static Function<Integer, Comparator<Book>> byHasExactAmountOfPages = Integer amountOfPages -> (Book book1, Book book2) -> 
    {
         if(book1.nrOfPages.equals(amountOfPages) && book2.nrOfPages.equals(amountOfPages))
         {
             return 0;
         }
         else if(!book1.nrOfPages.equals(amountOfPages) && !book2.nrOfPages.equals(amountOfPages))
         {
             return 0;
         }
         else if(book1.nrOfPages.equals(amountOfPages) && !book2.nrOfPages.equals(amountOfPages))
         {
             return -1;
         }
         else
         {
             return 1;
         }
    };
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List.of(new Book(1), new Book(2), new Book(3)).stream()
            .sorted(byHasExactAmountOfPages.apply(2))
            .forEach(System.out::print);
    }
}
```

Comment: A lambda of a lambda is confusing to look at.  Imagine how much clearer it would be if you abandoned the use of Function and just wrote `static class PageCountComparator implements Comparator<Book>`, with a constructor that takes an Integer argument.  (Are you sure you want to use Integer rather than int?  Is it really okay for nrOfPages to be null?)

Comment: @VGR Thank you for your suggestions! I'll transfer them to my actual code at hand and compare both versions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the brackets around argument:

```
   here                   and here
    ( Integer amountOfPages ) -> (Book book1, Book book2) -> ...
```

Comment: And to explain why (presumably) @nistel is confused here: If you omit the type, _and_ there is just 1 argument, you can omit the parens: `amountOfPages -> (Book book1, Book book2) -> ....;` works fine. But if you have 0 or 2+ arguments, _or_ you want to use types, the parens are mandatory.